# Website citation in latex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

So I wanted to create a citation like the following:

- US. Census Bureau (2017). Retrieved from https://.....

I have tried the following:

```
@Online{USCensusBureau2017,
label = {United States Census Bureau},
Title = {Statistics of U.S. Businesses (SUSB)},
url = {https:...},
author = {United States Census Bureau},
year = {2017}
}
```

But it gives me a formatted bibliographic entry like this:

```
U.  S.  C.  Bureau.   Statistics  of  u.s.  businesses  (susb),  2017. URL https://.....
```

Could you tell me how I can achieve what I need? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your entry has a so-called "corporate" author. Left to its default parsing devices, BibTeX thinks that the author has a name that consists of three given names and one surname, "Bureau". To override the default parsing, you need to change `author = {United States Census Bureau},` to either `author = {{United States Census Bureau}},` or `author = {{US. Census Bureau}},`. This will make BibTeX think that the author has a single surname component, without given names.

Comment: Off-topic: You should also change `Title = {Statistics of U.S. Businesses (SUSB)},` to `Title = {Statistics of {U.S.} Businesses ({SUSB})},` in order to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing "US" and "SUSB".